# Variable naming convension for whether having

Tags: naming

Variable for whether having, for example, the variable for if the user has points, which is correct?

have_points, has_points, if_having_points or if_has_points?

Comment: convention for which language? Different languages have different 'standards'

Comment: I’d go with `has_points`. How are you computing/deriving/obtaining the value?

Comment: The question pops up while using Python but the question is for a general language..

Comment: Questions asking for naming recommendations, conventions, etc. are off-topic because they are opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming convention for a variable which holds boolean value should be indicated by prefixes like: is, has, have, does, will, can etc.

In your case you're using snake case. If "has Points" is being tracked for a single entity then you can go with `has_points`. For more than one entity you might want to go for `have_points`.

Although it boils to personal preference, but you should still try to keep your code short and succinct.